# Is it worth testing the same version of IE on different versions of Windows?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, testing, browser

I'm putting together some virtual machines to test different browsers and I'm wondering if there is any compelling reason to be able to test the same version of IE on different versions of Windows. (i.e. IE8 on XP and Vista) I'm mostly talking about testing CSS to make sure it "looks right" across browsers, but if there were major differences in JavaScript I would want to know that too.

Are different versions of IE "generally the same" on different versions of Windows? Thanks!

Comment: SImilar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607466/ie-6-7-on-windows-xp-vs-windows-vista

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with both people who have answered previously, despite the fact that they disagree with one another.

In general, IE will act very largely the same across all versions of windows.  However, there can be (and are) some occassional subtle differences.  Whether these are important are not is up to you.

For the great majority of websites, I wouldn't bother with it.  But for very precise web applications where you're using something like complex javascript, or if you require layout to be correct to the pixel for some reason, then it could be worth it.  I'm thinking of cases where people are generating os-type applications in JavaScript where the DOM is really being pushed around, and where exact layout and flawless event-handling is critical.

Comment: I left one thing out which might have clarified things: My role on this web application is closer to support mode. It is an implementation of a third party healthcare app. So when patients call the help desk and say a page "looks funny" I need to be able to mock their setup as close as possible. I guess the reason I asked the question was that it had to be a balance between getting what I need to do my job and spending manpower building a ton of VMs. Thanks all!

Answer (score 5):

The time and cost of testing different versions of windows would be better spent in other places.  This would be one of the last things I would look at when looking for rendering issues.

Comment: It's an enterprise thing so the cost is minimal, and I think time-wise I would probably isolate time to running through the various browsers. e.g. do regular developing by just running quick checks on Firefox and IE and then run a bunch of stuff through a suite of browsers. Thanks!

Comment: I was thinking more about man hour cost. It takes time to create the VM, and time to include it each phase of regression testing, etc. And all that time costs money.  Note that I'm not saying that this is a useless thing to test, just that it you probably shouldn't put time into this until you have most all of your other bases covered.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I am currently testing something out and have varying results between XP and Vista.

--assuming you already have both platforms.

Comment: What on earth is different? I use XP and Vista and I don't remember ever noticing different behavior in IE.

Comment: There are some differences in frames and frame alignment

Answer (score 0):

No, I would stick to testing on the current (IE8) and previous (IE7), unless it is a requirement to support older versions. These browsers should render the same across different versions of windows.

I personally dont bother with IE6, the sooner that is gone, the better

Answer (score 0):

I would think there would be very limited cases where you'll notice a difference in IE between Windows versions.  One example where you would is a Google toolbar bug I've seen in IE6 that renders html forms unusable.  That bug seems to go away when you upgrade to IE8.  But that problem is more Google Toolbar than IE.

Other differences you run into may be security or plug-in related.  But in the default IE configurations I don't think you'll see any differences in rendering.